# CTE SQL to update Master table based on a condition in Detail table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Looking for CTE SQL to avoid cursor or lazy SQL.

There are two tables "Master" & "Detail" linked by "MasterId". I want to update Master-table (IsAllClosed=1) if all rows in Detail-table are IsClose=0 against each MasterId.

**Master** table:

```
 MasterId     |     IsAllClosed
 -------------+-----------------
 10           |     0
 20           |     0
```

**Detail** table:

```
DetailId   |   MasterId      |     IsClosed
-----------+-----------------+--------------
101        |    10           |     0
102        |    10           |     1
103        |    10           |     0
104        |    20           |     1
105        |    20           |     1
```

Expected result:

```
 MasterId     |     IsAllClosed
 -------------+------------------
 10           |     0    -- All Detail Rows Are Not Closed
 20           |     1    -- All Detail Rows Are Closed
```

Here is the sample SQL to create both tables

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tblMaster;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tblDetail;

--Master Table
SELECT (MasterId), (0) IsAllClosed 
INTO #tblMaster 
FROM 
    (SELECT (10) MasterId 
     UNION 
     SELECT (20) MasterId) t

--Detail Table
SELECT (MasterId), (DetailId), (IsClosed) 
INTO #tblDetail 
FROM 
    (SELECT (10) MasterId, (101) DetailId, (0) IsClosed 
     UNION 
     SELECT (10) MasterId, (102) DetailId, (1) IsClosed 
     UNION 
     SELECT (10) MasterId, (103) DetailId, (0) IsClosed 
     UNION 
     SELECT (20) MasterId, (201) DetailId, (1) IsClosed 
     UNION 
     SELECT (20) MasterId, (202) DetailId, (1) IsClosed) t


SELECT * FROM [#tblMaster]
SELECT * FROM [#tblDetail]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to update to "1", you can use `not exists`:

```
update m
    set isallclosed = 1
    from master m
    where not exists (select 1
                      from detail d
                      where d.masterid = m.masterid and d.isclosed = 0
                     );
```

Note:  This will update master records with no detail records.  That technically meets your description, but I'm not 100% sure you really want that.

If you want to update both `0` and `1`s, then:

```
update m
    set isallclosed = d.isallclosed
    from master m join
         (select d.masterid, max(isclosed) as isallclosed
          from detail d
          group by d.masterid
         ) d
         on m.masteerid = d.masterid
    where m.isallclosed <> d.isallclosed;
```

This version, because if uses an inner join, only updates master records that have a detail record.

Note:  If `isclosed` is a `bit`, then `max()` requires a conversion to a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `SUB QUERY`

```
UPDATE [#tblMaster]
SET IsAllClosed=1 
FROM [#tblMaster] Z INNER JOIN (
SELECT MasterId FROM [#tblDetail]
GROUP BY MasterId
HAVING MIN(IsClosed)<>0) S ON Z.MasterId=S.MasterId
```